# Using Audacity, how do I split out separate speakers from a single track to multiple tracks?

Tags: audacity, track, voices

I have a single file containing a speaker and callers.

Assuming that I can discretely select each voice, how can I use Audacity to split the callers and the speaker into two separate tracks?

Answer (score 2):

This is the basis of editing. Select and blade the regions of audio that you need, and then move them to the requisite track. It's laborious, but that's the way it's done.